# Python: Syntax Error for imported module - 'codecs.py'

Tags: python, windows-xp

I'm using a script which imports some modules, one being `codecs`. When the script is executed, I'll get a `Traceback (most recent call last):` on the `import codecs` line and `SyntaxError: ('no viable alternative at input \'""\'', ('C:\\Python26\\lib\\codecs.py', 268, 17, '        return (b"", 0)\n'))`.  This only occurs when I'm executing my own script which in turn executes the script which imports the `codecs` module. If I directly execute the script through cmd, the error will not occur.

Answer (score 2):

> which in turn executes the script which ...

How does it ‘execute’ the script? You mean an import? A subprocess call? Something else?

Because “no viable alternative at input...” is a distinctive ANTLR parser error, and CPython 2.6 doesn't use that.

Jython 2.5 does. But Jython shouldn't be trying to run the `codecs` module from CPython 2.6. In this case it fails because of the syntax `b""` for byte strings which is new in Python 2.6.

Comment: I used `subprocess.Popen` to call the script. Running the script through cmd itself works fine. So is it a Python version incompatibility issue? 
I'm currently using ActivePython 2.6.5.12.

Comment: Well the guess from that error is, the called script is getting run by Jython instead of CPython. What's the command-line you're using? Does it include the `python.exe` path or are you relying on Windows file associations (best not)? Could the association point to Jython somehow? (This wouldn't explain how Jython would be importing CPython's libraries, but still.)

Comment: I'm using Windows XP's Command Prompt and I have `C:\Python26\python.exe` in my environment variable.

Comment: Yes, but what's the command line you're using to `Popen`? The contents of the `PATH` envvar won't matter if you're executing the `.py` file directly using Windows file associations.